# github tags and composer

Tags: github, tags, composer-php

I wonder why if I tag a package on github with f.e. `v1.0.0`, when I require it with composer it says:

> Importing tag v1.0.0 (1.0.0.0)

always adding one 0 to the tag given.

How does composer version matching works?

Answer (score 0):

Composer internally normalizes versions to 4 digits, to simplify comparison (`1.0` is the same as `1.0.0.0`). The thing what you're seeing here is normalized version of tag name.

You may take a look at [versions documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#stability-constraints) to see some examples.